# Python f-string null format specifier

Tags: python, string, python-3.8, f-string

Is there a way to specify a "null" formatter in the Python f-strings?

Python 3.8 introduced the '=' specifier in f-strings.
The code:

```py
n = 42
s = f'My favourite number is stored in variable {n=}'
print(s)
```

will print `My favourite number is stored in variable n=42`.

Is there a way for f-strings to use only the variable, and not the value?
I would like to print `My favourite number is stored in variable n`.

I know this may seem silly, and that there are other ways to achieve this results (for instance, I could process the f-string with a regular expression to remove the undesired part).
But I am still wondering if this is currently possible with regular f-strings.

Since f-strings implementation have a way to know the variable (and not only the value), it would seem logical that they had the option to render only the variable.

Answer (score 2):

```py
n = 42
s = f'My favourite number is stored in variable {n=}'.split('=')[0]
print(s)
```

Output: My favorite number is stored in variable n

**EDIT -> Alternative:** If you would like to use `{var=}` more than once in your f-string and assuming you do not want to use the `=` character anywhere else in the string you can use it as a delimiter on both sides of your variable.

```py
s = f'My favourite number is stored in variable {n=}= or {m=}='
s = s.split('=')

j = 0
for i in s:
    print(list(s)[j], end='')
    j += 2
    if j >= len(s):
        break
```

This solution is not valid if you do intend to use the `=` character in your string for anything other than delimiter, however, it's the simplest one I found that matches the example you provided. If that does not match your use case please reference @Fzovpec's solution.

Comment: This implementation works if the only = sign is the one right after n. If there are other = symbols, the resulting string would be incorrect, only a portion of the desired string would be assigned to variable s.

Comment: @EnricoGandini check the edit and see if that matches your use case. Let me know what you think

Comment: thank you for your answer, I think some people will find it useful, knowing that you cannot use the = character in your string (as you explained in the answer). Still, it is not the answer I was looking for. I was looking for some f-string functionality to achieve my result. I thought that f-strings had some functionality I was not aware of, so I asked, but probably that is not the case.

Comment: It is an interesting question, however, I'm afraid f-strings do not have such functionality. Thanks for the discussion!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you wanna use this implementation.

**Way 1**

```
print('My favourite number is stored in variable n')
```

**Way 2**

Otherwise, u should write much more code

```
n = 42

variables = {'n': n}
location = list(variables.keys())[list(variables.values()).index(n)]
s = f'My favourite number is stored in variable {location}'

print(s)
```

Comment: Yes, I was aware of those methods. You are right, they are probably the way to go. What I do not like of those implementations is that some "code duplication" is introduced: you have to keep track of the variable n and of an identical string 'n'. What if for some reason you want to rename the variable, from n to my_number? You would also have to rename all the strings from 'n' to 'my_number'. I thank you for your answer, but it does not really answer my question: can I achieve my result with some features of Python f-strings?